# Usage of EN4B command

Tags: c, spi

Can anybody explains the usage of EN4B command of micron SPI chips.
I want to know the difference between 3 byte and 4 byte address mode in SPI.
I was going through the SPI drivers where I found this commands.
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a legacy point of view, *SPI* commands have always used 3 bytes for the address interested by their operation.
This was fine as with 24 bits it is possible to address up to 128MiB.

When the Flashes grew larger it was needed to switch from 3 bytes to 4 bytes addressing.

Whenever you have any doubts regarding the hardware you can find the answers in the proper **datasheet**, I don't know what specific chip you are referring to however.

I found the [Micron N25Q512A](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/data-sheet/nor-flash/serial-nor/n25q/n25q_512mb_1ce_3v_65nm.pdf) NOR Flash, which is 512MiB so it needs a form of 4 bytes addressing; from it you can learn that

1. There are 3 bytes legacy commands and new 4 bytes commands.
   For example *03h* and *13h* for the single read.
2. You can supply a default fourth address byte with a specific register.
   The *Extended Address Register* let you choose the region of the flash for the legacy commands.
3. You can enable 4 bytes addressing for legacy command.
   Either write the appropriate bit in the *Nonvolatile Configuration Register* or use the *ENTER / EXIT 4-BYTE ADDRESS MODE* (opcodes *B7h* and *E9h* respectively)

[This Linux patch](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-mtd/2013-August/047957.html) also have some insights, basically telling that some chips only support one of the three points above.
Macronix seems to have first opted for the number *3* only and Spansion for the number *1*.
Checking some datasheet of theirs seems to suggests that now both support all three methods.